# Как использовать Python requests с дополнительными IP сервера?

Tags: python, requests, ip

Есть VPS сервер на Ubuntu 18.04. У провайдера купил и привязал дополнительные IP адреса.
Как мне создавать запросы на внешний ресурс, используя определенный IP?
Используется requests.post, язык Python3+

Пример, как должно работать:

```
requests.post('https://google.com', IP1)
requests.post('https://google.com', IP2)
```

Где IP1 и 2 - это дополнительные внешние IP адреса указанные в сетевых настройках Ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

```
IP = ('1.1.1.1','1.1.1.2')
for i in IP:
    requests.post('https://google.com', i)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Так а что не так, что конкретно автор хочет?